# Jersey Client and CXF mixed up (multipart issue)

Tags: java, spring, rest, jersey, cxf

I have a legacy app that mixes both CXF and jersey-client.
**When I am using the Jersey Client but CXF takes over.**

```
 Response response = client
            .target("http://example.com") 
            .register(MultiPartFeature.class) //error when run this line
            .request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON )accept type
            .put(Entity.entity(request, mediaType), Response.class);
```

When using a jersey client to retrieve multipart from a jersey server, this action is handled by cxf and throw error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.InstantiationException: org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.internal.FormDataParamValueFactoryProvider
21:09:51,574 INFO  [stdout] (default task-31)   at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.impl.ConfigurationImpl.createProvider(ConfigurationImpl.java:208) ~[cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
21:09:51,574 INFO  [stdout] (default task-31)   at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.impl.ConfigurationImpl.register(ConfigurationImpl.java:176) ~[cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
21:09:51,574 INFO  [stdout] (default task-31)   at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.impl.ConfigurableImpl.register(ConfigurableImpl.java:91) ~[cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
21:09:51,574 INFO  [stdout] (default task-31)   at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.impl.ConfigurableImpl.doRegister(ConfigurableImpl.java:117) ~[cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
21:09:51,574 INFO  [stdout] (default task-31)   at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.impl.ConfigurableImpl.register(ConfigurableImpl.java:108) ~[cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
```

There is an issue
[enter link description here](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/issues/1649)

Comment: Use JerseyClientBuilder instead of ClientBuilder. The latter will default to using the CXF client.

Comment: I tried by using JerseyClientBuilder but failed again.same error throwed. @PaulSamsotha

Comment: Can you update your post with the code you are using?

Comment: `Response response = JerseyClientBuilder.newClient()
                .target("http://example.com")
                .register(JacksonFeature.class)
                .register(MultiPartFeature.class) //** same error like upside
                .request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON ) //add request header accept type
                .put(Entity.entity(request, mediaType), Response.class); //build Http Put mthod;` @PaulSamsotha                                                                                 failed with same error

Comment: And this is a client side error, not a server side error?

Comment: Yes, Client side @PaulSamsotha

Comment: Don't use `newClient()`. That is inherited from `ClientBuilder`, which has the default behavior I was referring to. Use `JerseyClientBuilder.createClient()` or instantiate the builder, call some methods on it, then call `build(). You can look at the [source code](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/2.27/core-client/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/client/JerseyClientBuilder.java)

Comment: Yes yes yes It's worked :) ==> THANKS A LOT @PaulSamsotha

Answer (score 4):

Use `JerseyClientBuilder` instead of `ClientBuilder`. The latter will default to using the CXF client. And don't use `JerseyClientBuilder.newClient()`. That is inherited from `ClientBuilder` (which `JerseyClientBuilder` extends), so it has the default behavior previously mentioned about defaulting to using CXF. Use `JerseyClientBuilder.createClient()` or instantiate the builder, call some methods on it, then call `build()`. You can look at the [source code](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jersey/blob/master/core-client/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/client/JerseyClientBuilder.java).

Comment: Hello Paul, how you've done that? Link is broken (page not found)

Comment: Thank you @Paul, can you please check this one too? Is about jersey: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66233389/upload-inputstream-file-and-string-filename-through-jersey-do-not-work